# Why is env different in an Azure ML notbook and an Azure ML terminal?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I'm using MS Azure ML and have found that when I start a Notebook (from the Azure ML Studio) it is executing in a a different environment than if I create a Python script and run it from the studio. I want to be able to create a specific environment and have the Notebook use that. The environment that the Notebook seems to run does not contain the packages I need and I want to preserve different environments.

Comment: Check which kernel is being used in the notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open a terminal, using the same compute target as you want to use with your Notebook afterwards, and to use and **existing environment** you can do:

```
conda activate existing_env
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name existing_env --display-name "Python 3.8 - Existing Environment"
```

However, to create a **new environment** and use it in you AzureML Notebook, you have to do the following commands:

```
conda create --name new_env python=3.8
conda activate new_env
conda install pip
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name new_env --display-name "Python 3.8 - New Environment"
```

And then last, but not least, you have to edit the Jupyter Kernel display names:

**IMPORTANT** Please ensure you are comfortable running all these steps:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
cd <folder-that-matches-the-kernel-of-your-environment>
sudo nano kernel.json
```

Then edit the name to match what you want and save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pip, Conda, Docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=&type=image) & [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) we can create ML environments for your own scripts.

> I want to be able to create a specific environment

To manually create an environment,

```
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
Environment(name="myenv")
```

Use Conda dependencies or pip requirement files for creating an environment using below code:

```
#### From a Conda specification file
myenv = Environment.from_conda_specification(name = "myenv",
                                             file_path = "path-to-conda-specification-file")

#### From a pip requirements file
myenv = Environment.from_pip_requirements(name = "myenv",
                                          file_path = "path-to-pip-requirements-file")
```

> The environment that the Notebook seems to run does not contain the packages I need and I want to preserve different environments.

To add the packages to your environment, can use the Conda, pip or private wheel files but it is recommended to use ***CondaDependency*** class.

```
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies

myenv = Environment(name="myenv")
conda_dep = CondaDependencies()

#### Installs numpy version 1.17.0 conda package
conda_dep.add_conda_package("numpy==1.17.0")

#### Installs pillow package
conda_dep.add_pip_package("pillow")

#### Adds dependencies to PythonSection of myenv
myenv.python.conda_dependencies=conda_dep
```

Register your environment in workspace using the command `myenv.register(workspace=ws)`

`list(workspace)` the list the environments in the [workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment(class)?view=azure-ml-py#list-workspace-)

To run your specific environment:

```
from azureml.core import Run
Run.get_environment()
```

To install a Conda environment as a kernel in a notebook, see [add a new Jupyter kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-terminal#add-new-kernels) and the code should be followed in a same sequence:

```html
conda create --name newenv
conda activate newenv
conda install pip
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name newenv --display-name "Python (newenv)"
```

To add, change or remove the Jupyter Kernels, please refer this [article](https://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove).

Refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments) for more details