# How to run notebooks in Azure ML with a specified custom environment

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, environment

According to Microsoft's [Azure documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments)
You have to make an Environment class, and then run a python script configured with this environment.

How do you run a **notebook** with a specified environment, and not a script?
For example: I want create a notebook in Azure ML and run it with a custom environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is env different in an Azure ML notbook and an Azure ML terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571948/why-is-env-different-in-an-azure-ml-notbook-and-an-azure-ml-terminal)

Comment: [How do I use an environment in an ML Azure Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506398/how-do-i-use-an-environment-in-an-ml-azure-pipeline), [Can't change virtual environment within Azure ML notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69931411/cant-change-virtual-environment-within-azure-ml-notebook) and [How to use custom environment defined in the custom environments tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/764339/how-to-use-custom-environment-defined-in-the-custo.html)