# Is there a way to create virtual env (and kernel) in Azure ML notebook from a custom registered environment?

Tags: azure, conda, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I have registered a custom environment (through Environments tab) in Azure Machine Learning (providing Docker file and conda_dependencies.yaml) which I plan to use for training jobs. Now I would like to be able to use this environment also in AzureML notebooks for experimentation and development of code that I finally plan to use for the training jobs.

I am wondering whether there is a way to create a kernel in AzureML notebook that is based on the registered environment from the previous step?

I have followed multiple tutorials to do this, in particular:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/764339/how-to-use-custom-environment-defined-in-the-custo
- https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-virtual-environments-in-azure-ml-workspace-in-azure-portal-39245a34b370
- [How to run notebooks in Azure ML with a specified custom environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685853/how-to-run-notebooks-in-azure-ml-with-a-specified-custom-environment)

I am able to create new conda venv in AzureML notebook (in terminal session from conda_dependencies.yaml file or simply as new venv and install packages manually one by one) and create a new kernel based on this venv. What I am not able to do is to create the venv based on the registered environment that I have already created in the Environments tab. Based on the documentation ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.environment?view=azure-ml-py)) there should be a way to do this by using `Environment.build_local()` method, but it does not work for me.

I tried to run the following code:

```
from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
from azureml.core import Environment

ws = Workspace.from_config()

myenv = Environment.get(ws, 'my_previously_registered_environment')

myenv.build_local(ws)
```

This code runs only for few seconds and outputs the following:

```
Saving setup content into  /tmp/tmpXYZXYZXY
```

No new venv is created, at least I do not see it by running:

```
%conda env list
```

Am I using the `Environment.build_local()` method in a wrong way (or with wrong parameters)?

If there is no way to create venv in AzureML notebooks from registered environment using `Environment.build_local()`, is there at least a way to get the conda_dependencies.yaml file (that I used during environment registration) from AzureML notebook (e.g. is it saved somewhere in storage where I can access it from Python)? I am trying to be able to create the venv and kernel based on the registered environment by running a (simple) script(s) without any manual copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a custom environment with conda.yaml file
[image]

To get the yaml file from the custom environment you can use below code snippet:

```py
from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
from azureml.core import Environment
import os

ws = Workspace.from_config()
myenv = Environment.get(ws, 'my_conda_envtest')
myenv.save_to_directory("env2.yaml")
```

Above code will save the `conda_dependencies.yml`  in `env2.yaml` directory.
[image]

[image]

Then you can use this `conda_dependencies.yml` file to create `conda env` and `kernel` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunatelly, I am not able to reproduce your results. When I run your code I do not see conda_dependencies.yml file in the env2.yaml directory. Can you maybe share the whole definition of your my_conda_envtest environment (i.e. the Docker file)? Thanks.

Comment: If you are creating the custom environment with Docker file, the function will create only azureml_environment.json file. 
You will get the yaml file only if you create the environment with conda.yaml file (As shown in the solution with Environment Context)

Comment: I see, now I am able to get the same results.

Just for the clarification: When I was creating the Environment through the UI, I had to select the option "Use existing docker image with optional conda file" and then populate the conda file (only the conda file). In case I selected "Create a new docker context" and created both new docker file and conda file, then I was not able to get the conda file from notebook. I do not know the reason for this behavior, but at least now have a working solution.

Thank you very much @RishabhM for your answers, they were very helpful for me!

Comment: Plus additionally, if you define the environment in the way described in the previous comment (only through conda file, not Docker + conda files), then it works to call just the `build_local()` function as described in the original post.

Comment: What if the environment is not a conda env?  i.e. based on a Docker file that also includes a `pip install` call but nothing else.